# Find process id and assign it to variable in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, process, pid

I have to write small bash script in which I have to find process ID in ubuntu and kill it.
As an example I would like to kill gedit.
In console I can do it with command

```
top | grep gedit
```

this show mi PID of process

later i can use

```
kill process_id
```

I don't know how i can do it using script. Do You have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:):)

```
#!/bin/bash
PID=`pgrep gedit`
kill $PID
echo "$PID is dead"
```